# Disabling/Enabling logging when using syslog

Tags: c, logging, syslog

I intend to use syslog for logging in an application. I need to be able to disable logging, at compile time, perhaps using a macro. Is this possible to do with the syslog facilities, or do I need to wrap syslog in my own macros/functions? The ability to disable/enable log messages based on their priority is a plus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could wrap a call to [setlogmask](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/libc/manual/html_node/setlogmask.html#setlogmask) in define block.

> **setlogmask** sets a mask (the “logmask”) that determines which future
>   syslog calls shall be ignored. If a program has not called setlogmask,
>   syslog doesn't ignore any calls. You can use setlogmask to specify
>   that messages of particular priorities shall be ignored in the future.

something like this :

```
#ifdef LOG_LEVEL1
setlogmask (LOG_UPTO (LOG_NOTICE));
#endif
#ifdef LOG_LEVEL2
setlogmask (LOG_UPTO (LOG_WARNING));
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I didn't know about setlogmask. This isn't exactly what I wanted, but it seems to be the best I can get.